# Must render buffer texture dimensions be power-of-two?

Tags: webgl

Does the texture that we use for WebGL render buffer storage need to have dimensions that are power-of-two?

### Background info

I'm chasing a FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT reported by a client on this setup:

Windows 7 Enterprise 32-Bit
Firefox Version: 33
Video Card: Intel Q45/Q43 Express Chipset Driver Version 8.13.10.2413

and so far I'm at a loss as to why it's happening, so guessing it might be something to do with NPOT textures.

Here's my render buffer implementation, which does not have power-of-two-texture yet:

```js
SceneJS._webgl.RenderBuffer = function (cfg) {

    /**
     * True as soon as this buffer is allocated and ready to go
     * @type {boolean}
     */
    this.allocated = false;

    this.canvas = cfg.canvas;
    this.gl = cfg.canvas.gl;
    this.buf = null;
    this.bound = false;
};

/**
 * Called after WebGL context is restored.
 */
SceneJS._webgl.RenderBuffer.prototype.webglRestored = function (_gl) {
    this.gl = _gl;
    this.buf = null;
};

/**
 * Binds this buffer
 */
SceneJS._webgl.RenderBuffer.prototype.bind = function () {
    this._touch();
    if (this.bound) {
        return;
    }
    this.gl.bindFramebuffer(this.gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.buf.framebuf);
    this.bound = true;
};


SceneJS._webgl.RenderBuffer.prototype._touch = function () {

    var width = this.canvas.canvas.width;
    var height = this.canvas.canvas.height;

    if (this.buf) { // Currently have a buffer
        if (this.buf.width == width && this.buf.height == height) { // Canvas size unchanged, buffer still good
            return;
        } else { // Buffer needs reallocation for new canvas size
            this.gl.deleteTexture(this.buf.texture);
            this.gl.deleteFramebuffer(this.buf.framebuf);
            this.gl.deleteRenderbuffer(this.buf.renderbuf);
        }
    }

    this.buf = {
        framebuf: this.gl.createFramebuffer(),
        renderbuf: this.gl.createRenderbuffer(),
        texture: this.gl.createTexture(),
        width: width,
        height: height
    };

    this.gl.bindFramebuffer(this.gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.buf.framebuf);
    this.gl.bindTexture(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.buf.texture);
    this.gl.texParameteri(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, this.gl.NEAREST);
    this.gl.texParameteri(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, this.gl.NEAREST);
    this.gl.texParameteri(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, this.gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    this.gl.texParameteri(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, this.gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   

    try {
        // Do it the way the spec requires
        this.gl.texImage2D(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, this.gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, this.gl.RGBA, this.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
    } catch (exception) {
        // Workaround for what appears to be a Minefield bug.
        var textureStorage = new WebGLUnsignedByteArray(width * height * 3);
        this.gl.texImage2D(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, this.gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, this.gl.RGBA, this.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureStorage);
    }

    this.gl.bindRenderbuffer(this.gl.RENDERBUFFER, this.buf.renderbuf);
    this.gl.renderbufferStorage(this.gl.RENDERBUFFER, this.gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height);
    this.gl.framebufferTexture2D(this.gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.buf.texture, 0);
    this.gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(this.gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, this.gl.RENDERBUFFER, this.buf.renderbuf);
    this.gl.bindTexture(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
    this.gl.bindRenderbuffer(this.gl.RENDERBUFFER, null);
    this.gl.bindFramebuffer(this.gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    // Verify framebuffer is OK
    this.gl.bindFramebuffer(this.gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.buf.framebuf);

    if (!this.gl.isFramebuffer(this.buf.framebuf)) {
        throw SceneJS_error.fatalError(SceneJS.errors.ERROR, "Invalid framebuffer");
    }

    var status = this.gl.checkFramebufferStatus(this.gl.FRAMEBUFFER);

    switch (status) {

        case this.gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE:
            break;

        case this.gl.FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT:
            throw SceneJS_error.fatalError(SceneJS.errors.ERROR, "Incomplete framebuffer: FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT");

        case this.gl.FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT:
            throw SceneJS_error.fatalError(SceneJS.errors.ERROR, "Incomplete framebuffer: FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT");

        case this.gl.FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS:
            throw SceneJS_error.fatalError(SceneJS.errors.ERROR, "Incomplete framebuffer: FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS");

        case this.gl.FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED:
            throw SceneJS_error.fatalError(SceneJS.errors.ERROR, "Incomplete framebuffer: FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED");

        default:
            throw SceneJS_error.fatalError(SceneJS.errors.ERROR, "Incomplete framebuffer: " + status);
    }

    this.bound = false;
};

/**
 * Clears this renderbuffer
 */
SceneJS._webgl.RenderBuffer.prototype.clear = function () {
    if (!this.bound) {
        throw "Render buffer not bound";
    }
    this.gl.clear(this.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | this.gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    this.gl.disable(this.gl.BLEND);
};

/**
 * Reads buffer pixel at given coordinates
 */
SceneJS._webgl.RenderBuffer.prototype.read = function (pickX, pickY) {
    var x = pickX;
    var y = this.canvas.canvas.height - pickY;
    var pix = new Uint8Array(4);
    this.gl.readPixels(x, y, 1, 1, this.gl.RGBA, this.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pix);
    return pix;
};

/**
 * Unbinds this renderbuffer
 */
SceneJS._webgl.RenderBuffer.prototype.unbind = function () {
    this.gl.bindFramebuffer(this.gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    this.bound = false;
};

/** Returns the texture
 */
SceneJS._webgl.RenderBuffer.prototype.getTexture = function () {
    var self = this;
    return {
        bind: function (unit) {
            if (self.buf && self.buf.texture) {
                self.gl.activeTexture(self.gl["TEXTURE" + unit]);
                self.gl.bindTexture(self.gl.TEXTURE_2D, self.buf.texture);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },
        unbind: function (unit) {
            if (self.buf && self.buf.texture) {
                self.gl.activeTexture(self.gl["TEXTURE" + unit]);
                self.gl.bindTexture(self.gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
            }
        }
    };
};

/** Destroys this buffer
 */
SceneJS._webgl.RenderBuffer.prototype.destroy = function () {
    if (this.buf) {
        this.gl.deleteTexture(this.buf.texture);
        this.gl.deleteFramebuffer(this.buf.framebuf);
        this.gl.deleteRenderbuffer(this.buf.renderbuf);
        this.buf = null;
        this.bound = false;
    }
};
```

Comment: As long as your texture`WRAP`mode is set to `CLAMP_TO_EDGE` there is no restriction

Comment: Have you tried running the WebGL conformance tests. These ones in particular [test1](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/renderbuffers/framebuffer-test.html?webglVersion=1) [test2](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/textures/texture-attachment-formats.html?webglVersion=1). If they fail then the user's driver needs to be updated or the browsers need to blacklist it. If they pass then looking at the differences between your code and tests might reveal the issue.

Comment: [Try this test too](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/renderbuffers/framebuffer-object-attachment.html?webglVersion=1)

Comment: Awesome thanks gman, I'll send the client those tests to try.

Comment: BTW. Ken Russell just suggested allocating a DEPTH_STENCIL renderbuffer as well, in case the driver requires it, which I'll try as well. Client's in a different continent and I don't have that setup, so...will take a little while to confirm, I'll get back to yiz.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could find (I don't use WebGL), the WebGL spec delegates to the OpenGL ES 2.0 spec on these FBO related calls. RGBA with 8 bits per component is not a format that is supported as render target in ES 2.0. Many devices do support it (advertised with the OES_rgb8_rgba8 extension), but it is not part of the standard.

The texture you are using as `COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` is RGBA with 8-bit components:

```
this.gl.texImage2D(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, this.gl.RGBA, width, height, 0,
                   this.gl.RGBA, this.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureStorage);
```

Try specifying this as RGB565, which is color renderable:

```
this.gl.texImage2D(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, this.gl.RGBA, width, height, 0,
                   this.gl.RGB, this.gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, textureStorage);
```

If you do need an alpha component in the texture, RGBA4444 or RGB5_A1 are your only portable options:

```
this.gl.texImage2D(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, this.gl.RGBA, width, height, 0,
                   this.gl.RGBA, this.gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4, textureStorage);
this.gl.texImage2D(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, this.gl.RGBA, width, height, 0,
                   this.gl.RGBA, this.gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1, textureStorage);
```

The spec actually looks somewhat contradictory to me. Under "Differences Between WebGL and OpenGL ES 2.0", it says:

> The following combinations of framebuffer object attachments, when all of the attachments are framebuffer attachment complete, non-zero, and have the same width and height, must result in the framebuffer being framebuffer complete:
>   COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE texture

Which at first sight suggests that `RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE` is supported. But that's under the condition "when all of the attachments are framebuffer attachment complete", and according to the ES 2.0 spec, attachments with this format are **not** attachment complete. And there is no override in the WebGL spec on what "attachment complete" means.

Comment: WebGL **requires** RGBA with 8 bits per component. That was the point of the section you quoted. ES 2.0 does not require that but it does not disallow it. WebGL requires on top of minimum ES 2.0 support several other minimums, this is one of them. In fact, ES doesn't require ANY formats renderable RGB565, RGBA444, RGB5_A1, etc but WebGL does require the 3 specified in the spec to work everywhere.

Comment: @gman I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the last part. ES 2.0 clearly specifies RGBA4, RGBA5_A1 and RGB565 as color-renderable. See table 4.5 in the spec document.

Comment: RGBA4, RGBA5_A1 and RGB565 are Renderbuffer formats. The code above is using textures, not renderbuffers for its color attachments. Table 4.5 is about renderbuffers, not textures. Also, regardless of that part of section 4.5 just page down it says a framebuffer is incomplete if *The combination of internal formats of the attached images does not violate an implementation-dependent set of restrictions*. In other words ES says the driver can reject any combination of attachments period and still be spec compliant. WebGL on the other hand requires 3 specific combinations to work. Others may work.